# How to iterate over a json object list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am struggling how to sum all the values of "B" in my json object. I want the console log to show me the grand total of all the "B" values.

```
var voltot = 0;

$.each(json,function(k,v){

    voltot = v.B += voltot ;

    //console.log(v.B);

});

console.log(voltot);
```

HERE IS MY FULL JSON OBJECT.

```js
var json=
[
    {
        "a": "OOCBER",
        "b": "OOCL BERLIN",
        "c": "CHINA",
        "d": "GREAT BRITAIN",
        "e": "*PI",
        "f": "NGB",
        "g": "CN",
        "i": "GB",
        "n": 9,
        "o": 6,
        "p": "2015-09-14",
        "q": "2015-09-14",
        "s": 4,
        "u": "40HC",
        "v": "TRLU7564566",
        "w": "CN0794909",
        "x": "LEIGH",
        "y": "NINGBO",
        "z": 395,
        "B": 68.8,
        "C": 7987.5,

    },
    {
        "a": "OOCBER",
        "b": "OOCL BERLIN",
        "c": "CHINA",
        "d": "GREAT BRITAIN",
        "e": "*PI",
        "f": "NGB",
        "g": "CN",
        "i": "GB",
        "n": 9,
        "o": 6,
        "p": "2015-09-14",
        "q": "2015-09-14",
        "s": 4,
        "u": "40HC",
        "v": "TCLU8306124",
        "w": "CN0786008",
        "x": "OXFORDSHIRE",
        "y": "NINGBO",
        "z": 412,
        "B": 68,
        "C": 8790.5,

    }
]
```

i am struggling how to sum all the values of "B" in my json object. I want the console log to show me the grand total of all the "B" values.

```
var voltot = 0;

$.each(json,function(k,v){

    voltot = v.B += voltot ;

    //console.log(v.B);

});

console.log(voltot);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method to obtain an unique value from an array is the [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) method, which takes a callback function and a starting value (it **reduces** an array to a single value). You could use it this way :

```
json.reduce(function(total, current) { return typeof current.B === "number" ? total + current.B : total; }, 0);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cam8q6gs/1/).

Comment: @user5554551 are you maybe using IE 8 ? Array.prototype.reduce is specified in ECMA 5.1 so it should be implemented in all modern browser, but if you need there's a polyfill defined on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill)

Comment: @user5554551 I updated my answer (and JSFiddle) to account for the fact that all your objects do not possess a .B field. That may fix your NaN problem. Edit : oops, they all have. That's your browser not following ECMA 5.1 then.

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea what that might work now and not before :-/ Did you get a NaN while using my JSFiddle as is, or after a modification?

Comment: Got Nan on the first fiddle then after your mod works a treat :)

Comment: Ok that's strange, all I did was add an apparently useless "field not defined" check and update your JSON object to the full one. Anyway I'm glad it works, reduce really is the right tool for the job here, even if other solutions based on forEach or other will work too.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong

```
voltot = v.B += voltot ;
```

Make like this

```
voltot += v.B;
```

Or

```
voltot = v.B + voltot ;
```

Comment: When I do that i get NaN in the console.

Comment: @user5554551 Does every index on the array have a B?

Comment: Out of curiosity and off-topic: Why does this not work? "=" and "+=" have the same precedence and should get executed "right-to-left". So this should effectively become: `voltot = (v.B += voltot)`, which in my mind, should work as expected.

Comment: Yes every index i want to add together to get an overall sum starts with a capital B

Comment: It won't be enough to have the index _start with a capital B_ - the index has to actually *be* a capital B.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vha6fv6/). I just shrunk json and post. Try with full json array

```
var json=
[
    {

        "z": 395,
        "B": 68,
        "C": 7987.5,

    },
  {

        "z": 395,
        "B": 68,
        "C": 7987.5, 
    }
];

var voltot = 0;

$.each(json,function(k,v){
    voltot += v.B;
});

console.log(voltot);
```

Comment: Can you post your full json?

Answer (score 0):

The operator += is incorrect. @RiccardoC answer was correct.

Also, you don't need to use jquery to sum the values. You could simply do the following

```
var voltot=0;
json.forEach(function(element) {voltot+=element.B})
```

The forEach function will run a callback for each element of your array

Comment: `.map()` translates every value of an array into a new one. You should be using `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: @Andreas a reduce would be even more appropriate.

Comment: example? NaN in console